# How do you move files to Windows Server 2008 cloud server from local computer?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I recently setup a Windows 2008 R2 server on Amazon EC2. I now want to move an application I created on my local desktop to this server. However, having never done this before I have no idea how to transfer files from my local desktop to the online server. What is the standard convention for transferring files from local machine to the server?

Comment: How would you transfer files to any remote computer?  Do that.  @MDMarra's answer has specifics suggestions but that's the gist - the same way you'd transfer files to any remote machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map a drive, share the drive via RDP, use FTP(S), etc.

Your second question is unanswerable. Read the How To Ask section of the site, please.

Comment: Is osmosis an acceptable method of transferring files?

Comment: Thanks. I just found this thread on superuser http://superuser.com/questions/387501/how-do-you-download-files-on-a-windows-server . I shared the drive via RDP.